# Cmake can not find local version of opencv on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I have a version of OpenCV ((3.4.1) compiled and installed in /home/m/locals/opencv

the content of /home/m/locals/opencv is:

```
bin
include
lib
share
```

I have an eniroment pointing to this directory:

```
echo $OPENCV_ROOT
/home/m/locals/opencv
```

I have a cmake that tries to add opencv to project:

```
 file(TO_CMAKE_PATH $ENV{OPENCV_ROOT} OpenCV_DIR)
 set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
 find_package(OpenCV  COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc imgcodecs videoio photo stitching flann ml features2d calib3d objdetect REQUIRED)
```

when I run cmake, I am getting this error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake:399 (message):
The imported target "opencv_core" references the file

     "/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so.3.4.0"

   but this file does not exist.  Possible reasons include:

   * The file was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

   * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

   * The installation package was faulty and contained

      "/usr/local/share/OpenCV/OpenCVModules.cmake"

   but not all the files it references.
```

My questions:

1. Why it is trying to find OpenbCV 3.4.0, when the one that i installed is 3.4.1
2. How can I fix it and make msure that it points to the correct copy of openCV?

Comment: What is "Linux 18.04"? Ubuntu 18,04?

Comment: Firstly check, that your OpenCV installation contains file `OpenCVConfig.cmake` (probably, under `share/`). As for `OpenCV_DIR` variable, it is better to set *environment variable* (in the shell, before calling `cmake`): `export OpenCV_DIR=/home/m/locals/opencv`. If you want to set `OpenCV_DIR` as *CMake variable*, it should refer to directory with `OpenCVConfig.cmake` file, not just installation prefix of OpenCV.

Comment: It seems you've previously installed a version of OpenCV in `/usr/local/`, this is why there's an `OpenCVModules.cmake` file in `/usr/local/share/OpenCV`. Either reinstall OpenCV in `/usr/local/` or make sure all the previously installed files are properly removed. Also as @Tsyvarev mentioned, set all the environment variables properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `export OpenCV_DIR=...` as commented by @Tsyvarev. However, it may affect other builds that requires exactly `3.4.0`. Rather, set the variable in your project's `CMakeLists.txt`

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /home/m/locals/opencv/share/OpenCV)
```

or, you can set the variable manually when running cmake:

```
cmake -D OpenCV_DIR=/home/m/locals/opencv/share/OpenCV ..
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by fully removing OpenCV and build it from the source.
[This](https://gist.github.com/luke-han/55047815e0dc2c446f5e184d9d0201cc) helped me to install OpenCV 3.3 in ubuntu 18.04